# Wordwrap to multiple cells in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a excel VBA macro that auto-fills a form using data from another sheet.

because this form needs to print on 1 page (higher ups in my company say so), I cannot have excel expand a cell to fit the text with word wrap.

what i need to figure out is how to make excel wordwrap text across 3-4 rows.

I've tried using formulas to mimic word wrap, but it doesn't come out very well (text appears missing or cut off)

EDIT: I have 4 rows with cells spanning different numbers of columns for each row. Example: the first cell spans 5 columns, I'd like it to over flow to the next row which has a cell spanning 10 columns, and that cell would overflow to the cell in the next row,  and so on

Comment: You can "Merge Cells". Google it.

Comment: My mistake I should have added that the rows span across a different number of columns for each row. So merging cells is not an option

Comment: You should give an example of what you mean. "Across 3-4 rows" isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight the cells that you need, right-click, select 'Merge Cells', then select wrap text.

This will create one larger cell in which you can type.